# Set a DependencyProperty value inside a StoryBoard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, dependency-properties, datatrigger

I wanted to trigger an animation from the ViewModel layer so I created a boolean DependencyProperty and a DataTrigger bound to it.

After the animation is over, I would like to reset the DependencyProperty value to False so I can trigger the animation again, but this seems not to work, the DependencyProperty is never set back to False.

**The DP declaration :**

```
public bool SlidingInLeft {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(SlidingInLeftProperty); }
    set {
        Console.WriteLine("SlidingInLeft: " + value);
        SetValue(SlidingInLeftProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SlidingInLeftProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SlidingInLeft", typeof(bool), typeof(OperationsListPageVM), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

**The XAML :**

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SlidingInLeft}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UserControl.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" SpeedRatio=".25" From="2000" To="0" Duration="0:0:.25" />
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UserControl.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="SlidingInLeft">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

(Note that the DataContext is set to the ViewModel object)

**Edit: The "whole" code, if it's can be of any help:**

**OperationsListPageVM.cs :**

```
namespace MaintenanceModule.ViewModel {
    public class OperationsListPageVM : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        #region propriétés
        public ObservableCollection<OperationVM> AllOperations { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<OperationVM> DisplayedOperations { get; set; }
        public static OperationsListPageVM Instance { get; private set; }

        public IPageVM PreviousPage { get; set; }
        public IPageVM NextPage { get; set; }

        public bool SlidingInLeft {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(SlidingInLeftProperty); }
            set {
                Console.WriteLine("SlidingInLeft: " + value);
                SetValue(SlidingInLeftProperty, value);
            }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty SlidingInLeftProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SlidingInLeft", typeof(bool), typeof(OperationsListPageVM), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        #endregion

        #region singleton
        private OperationsListPageVM() {
            AllOperations = new ObservableCollection<OperationVM>();
            AllOperations.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => {
                switch (args.Action) {
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                        foreach (OperationVM ovm in args.NewItems) {
                            DisplayedOperations.Add(ovm);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            };
            DisplayedOperations = new ObservableCollection<OperationVM>();
        }

        public static OperationsListPageVM GetInstance() {
            return Instance ?? (Instance = new OperationsListPageVM());
        }

        #endregion

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**OperationsListPageV.xaml :**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MaintenanceModule.View.Pages.OperationsListPageV"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:TactileWPFComponents;assembly=TactileWPFComponents"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MaintenanceModule.ViewModel"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=OperationsListPage}">
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="UserControl.RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SlidingInLeft}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UserControl.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" SpeedRatio="1" From="2000" To="0" Duration="0:0:.25" />
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UserControl.Visibility)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="SlidingInLeft">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../Resources/Images/GlassBlockZoneRecipeFlow.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>

        <lib:ScrollViewerFriction Margin="0, 20">
            <lib:WatchList ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedOperations}" Margin="20">
                <lib:WatchList.Resources>
                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.25" Color="Gray"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.75" Color="Gray"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Transparent"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                    <Style x:Key="StyleListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.25" Color="Gray"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.75" Color="Gray"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Transparent"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </lib:WatchList.Resources>
                <ListBox.BorderThickness>0</ListBox.BorderThickness>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem"/>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <lib:WatchList.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:OperationVM">

                        <Grid Margin="0, 10">

                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#050670"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>

                            <Grid.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../Resources/Images/Frame4.png"/>
                            </Grid.Background>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{Binding Color}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding CycleDuration}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextElement.FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EstimatedDate, StringFormat='{}{0:D}'}"/>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                                <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="100" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding CyclePercentage}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CyclePercentage, StringFormat=\{0:N0\}%}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </lib:WatchList.ItemTemplate>
            </lib:WatchList>
        </lib:ScrollViewerFriction>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**OperationsListPageV.xaml.cs :**

```
namespace MaintenanceModule.View.Pages {

    public partial class OperationsListPageV : UserControl, IPageV {
        public OperationsListPageVM OperationsListPage { get; set; }

        public OperationsListPageV() {
            OperationsListPage = OperationsListPageVM.GetInstance();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

in XAML:

```
<Storyboard Completed="Storyboard_Completed" >
```

in codebehind

```
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SetValue(SlidingInLeftProperty, false);
}
```

Comment: I finally did it by putting the Storyboard in resources and this Storyboard in the Storyboard parameter of BeginStoryboard. It works now. Is this an intended behavior? Why wouldn't the ExitActions trigger?